# Airflow Jinja Template dag_run.conf not parsing

Tags: jinja2, airflow

I have this dag code below.

```py
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from custom_operators.profile_data_and_update_test_suite_operator import ProfileDataAndUpdateTestSuiteOperator
from custom_operators.validate_data_operator import ValidateDataOperator
from airflow.models import Variable

connstring = Variable.get("SECRET_SNOWFLAKE_DEV_CONNECTION_STRING")

@dag('profile_and_validate_data', schedule_interval=None, start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"), catchup=False)
def taskflow():
    
    profile_data = ProfileDataAndUpdateTestSuiteOperator(
        task_id="profile_data",
        asset_name="{{ dag_run.conf['asset_name'] }}",
        data_format="sql",
        connection_string=connstring
    )
    
    validate_data = ValidateDataOperator(
        task_id="validate_data",
        asset_name="{{ dag_run.conf['asset_name'] }}",
        data_format="sql",
        connection_string=connstring,
        trigger_rule="all_done"
    )
    
    profile_data >> validate_data

dag = taskflow()
```

But the asset_name parameter is showing up the raw string of "{{ dag_run.conf['asset_name'] }}" rather than the configuration that is parsed when you trigger the dag and parsed with jinja.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `asset_name` registered as `template_fields` in `ValidateDataOperator`?

Answer (score 2):

BaseOperator has a field "template_fields" that contains all the field name that during the run Airflow would replace it values according to Jinja template.

You need to specify in your Custom Operators (ProfileDataAndUpdateTestSuiteOperator, ValidateDataOperator) the field "asset_name"

```
template_fields: Sequence[str] = (asset_name, )
```

Answer (score 0):

`render_template_as_native_obj` is set to `False` by default on the DAG. Setting it to `False` returns strings, change it `True` to get the native obj.

```
@dag('profile_and_validate_data', schedule_interval=None, start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"), catchup=False, render_template_as_native_obj=True)
```